# Access non static data member outside class

Tags: c++, non-static, datamember, data-members

Is it possible to access non static data members outside their class? Say you have an example like the following. I know it does not make much sense as an example, but I just want to understand how to access a non static data member. If the following is compiled it generates an error:

```
 C.h|70|error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘C::age’|
```

//C.h

```
class C{
  public:
    int age;
};
 int getAge();
```

//C.cpp

```
C::C()
{
    age  = 0;
}
int getAge(){
   return (C::age);
}
```

Comment: `int C::getAge()` would probably work better. Move the getter inside the class.

Comment: The point of classes is that each instance is separate. Which instance's `age` do you want to return?

Comment: @WhozCraig I know, I know that. Say I need that function outside that class. Is there a way to fix my error?

Comment: @chris The instance of age in class C

Comment: @FranXh, You have to realize that makes no sense whatsoever. You create whatever different objects of C you want and each has its own `age`. If you want one `age` for all instances (or accessible from no instance), you have to make `age` static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-static members are instance dependent. They are initialized when a valid instance is initialized.

The problem with your example is that, it tries to access a non-static member through the class interface without first initializing a concrete instance. This is not valid.

You can either make it `static`:

```
class C{
public:
    static int age;
};
```

which requires you to also define `age` before using at runtime by: `int C::age = 0`. Note that value of `C::age` can be changed at runtime if you use this method.

Or, you can make it `const static` and directly initialize it like:

```
class C{
public:
    const static int age = 0;
};
```

In this case, value of `C::age` is `const`.

Both of which will let you get it without an instance: `C::age`.

Comment: My age value will change, so I cannot declare it constant. I think making it static would be the best way, but when I do int C::age = 0 I get an error like this:

C.cpp|5|error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘C::age’|

Answer (score 3):

Without making it static, you would have to create a value:

Either an lvalue:

```
C c;

return c.age;
```

or an rvalue:

```
return C().age;
// or
return C{}.age;
```

The problem with your code is that you try to access the `age` member without creating an instance of the class. Non-static data members of a class are only accessible through an instance of the class, and in your case no instance is created.

Comment: I do have a constructor where I declare age=0

Comment: @FranXh oops. Thanks I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't is because local variables are allocated at runtime onto the stack - you can obtain its position if you really wanted to with some inline asm but it would require some debugging to obtain the stack position and the later (after the function) you want to access it the more likely it will have long been overwritten by something else.